# Django update model form with unique constraint

Tags: django, model, django-forms

What I'm trying to achieve is to update an instance with unique_together constraint via a model form.
I've a "relationnal" model, e.g. a model with three fields, all as foreign key fields. This model is referenced by an another one through a through attribut.
A part of my "relationnal" model :

```
class EnseignantUECentre(models.Model):
    statut = models.ForeignKey(StatutEnseignant, blank=False, null=False)
    enseignantue = models.ForeignKey('EnseignantUE', blank=False, null=False)
    centre = models.ForeignKey('Centre', blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('enseignantue', 'centre')
```

Two of theses fields, `enseignantue` and `centre`, are set once and for all.
Only `statut` can be updated.

I overloaded a `Form._post_clean` method to ensure that theses fields are not modified.

```
def _post_clean(self):
    # si lors d'un update les valeurs centre et enseignantue
    # changent il y a erreur: Voir #272
    super(EnseignantUECentreForm, self)._post_clean()
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    if 'centre' in self.changed_data:
        # on ne récupère pas la valeur depuis self.initial
        # mais depuis l'instance
        if self.instance is not None:
            self._update_errors(ValidationError({'centre': ValidationError("Le centre est déjà associé, vous ne pouvez le modifier")}))
    if 'enseignantue' in self.changed_data:
        if self.instance is not None:
            self._update_errors(ValidationError({'enseignantue': ValidationError("L'enseignantue est déjà associé, vous ne pouvez le modifier")}))
```

This code seems to working but while I debug it, I get a supplementary `ValidationError` filed in the `_all_` errors dict key.

It says :

```
ipdb> errors
{'__all__': [ValidationError([u'Enseignant ue centre with this Enseignantue and Centre already exists.'])]}
```

I'm instanciating my form as :

```
from ue.baobab.forms import EnseignantUECentreForm
from ue.baobab.models import EnseignantUECentre
v = {'centre': 214, 'enseignantue': 1, 'statut': 2}
instance = EnseignantUECentre.objects.filter(centre=214)[1]
f = EnseignantUECentreForm(instance=instance, data=v)
f.is_valid()
```

I understand that cleaning form process `BaseModelForm._post_clean` calls validation on the model side (validate_unique). But why the "update" process is not working here?
I'm missing something really obvious here! Is `Model.save(force_update=True)` could be of some help?

Thx a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do in format

```
self.add_error('centre', "error message")
```